# Multi-row datagrid to handle collection in a collection?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, expression-blend

I have the following data structures

```
class Car
{
    int CarID;
    string CarModel;
    string CarColor;
    string CarAge;
}

class Person
{
    int ID;
    string FirstName;
    string Surname;
    List<Car> Cars;
}
```

And I have people stored in an observable collection -

```
ObservableCollection<Person> People;
```

I need to display them in a DataGrid like this mockup -
[image]

As you can see, a Person can have either one or more Cars, and when they have multiple cars I want to show the details of the multiple cars in the same 'row'.

Is this possible with WPF? How would I set up bindings if so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

does the [RowDetailTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.rowdetailstemplate%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) do what you want? you can use it to display childrows the way you want. just google for it to see some more examples

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding People}">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
     <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding ID}"/>
     <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding FirstName}"/>
     <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Binding="{Binding Surname}"/>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
   <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
          <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Cars}">
           <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=CarModel}" Header="Model" />
           <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=CarAge}" Header="Age" />
          <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=CarColor}" Header="Color" />
         </DataGrid>
        </DataTemplate>
     </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: That reference pointed to SilverLight and it has no information on how to use it do display child rows.